# Is it possible to compile Linux runnable fmus from Dymola on Windows machine?

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi

I am trying to export a FMU from windows machine using Dymola, to be used on both Linux and Windows OS. I guess such fmu will have linux64 and linux32 binaries along with win32 and win64 ones. However, I am not sure how to trigger Dymola to generate binaries for Linux runnable fmu (if it possible to do that).

The Dymola (2020X) installation is using Visual Studio 2019 compiler with both 'Desktop development with C++' and 'Linux development with C++' options. My assumption was that 'Linux development with C++' would make Dymola to compile .so files, however I see only dlls included in the fmu.

[image: win]
[image: linux]

Comment: Do you have a SourceCodeExport License for Dymola? 
Then you can export your FMU with source code and add the Linux binaries e.g. with the help of fmpy (https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy; use fmpy-gui --> help --> compile platform binaries) on a Linux machine.

Comment: Christian, unfortunately currently I don't have access to SourceCodeExport license.

Comment: The cross-compilation feature is now available in Dymola 2022.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot create Windows and Linux binaries for FMU:s in one operation. Great suggestion, though.

Comment: Dag, hopefully the option will be available in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a network or nodelocked license? Maybe a dual boot/virtual machine could help.

Comment: Or run Linux in a virtual machine in parallel, easy setup especially if you have a network (shareable) license.